# Приложение для моментального добавления изображения в альбом ВК

Tags: google-chrome, c, вконтакте, c++

Никогда раньше не работал с подобными приложениями так что даже не представляю, как такое сделать.

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в браузере по правому клику на картинку появился новый пункт в меню "добавить в альбомчик", например. Потом появляется окошко с текстовым полем и кнопка "ок". После нажатия кнопки картинка вместе с введеным текстом (названием) попадают в контактовский альбом.

Это вообще реально написать в короткие сроки на C/C++ ?

Comment: С++ не очень подходящий язык для этого. Основным языком для написания плагинов под Chrome и Firefox является JavaScript.